# JDK 8 Crash on Linux with Intellij IDE

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, java-8

I'm facing a lot of crashs from the JDK installed on my machine, this is the version details of the JDK:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM (build openj9-0.17.0, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20191017_442 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 77c1cf708
OMR      - 20db4fbc
JCL      - 97b5ec8f383 based on jdk8u232-b09)
```

The logs of the error can be seen below:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f8c2cc76147, pid=12178, tid=12203
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.5+10) (build 11.0.5+10-b520.17)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.5+10-b520.17, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, concurrent mark sweep gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# J 1228 c2 java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.5 (162 bytes) @ 0x00007f8c2cc76147 [0x00007f8c2cc76040+0x0000000000000107]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P" (or dumping to /home/hamza/core.12178)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Xms128m -Xmx1956m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine -Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true -Dide.no.platform.update=true -XX:ErrorFile=/home/hamza/java_error_in_IDEA_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/hamza/java_error_in_IDEA.hprof -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2019.3 -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/home/hamza/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/193.5662.53.vmoptions -Didea.jre.check=true com.intellij.idea.Main

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz, 12 cores, 15G, Ubuntu 19.10
Time: Mon Dec 30 14:22:21 2019 CET elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f8bdc0ac000):  JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 4" [_thread_in_Java, id=12203, stack(0x00007f8beda62000,0x00007f8bedb63000)]
```

I tried the `ulimit -c unlimited` command but still getting the same error. Done some search on the web and find out that other people are facing the same problem but without any solution for the moment. Anyone having a clue of how to get rid of this?

Usage of JDK: running/developing a microservice architecture based application with Intellij IDE and in term of memory usage I'm not even reaching 10GB of the 16 in my laptop.

Comment: so is it _your_ machine or a _container_ on your machine? And this one failed on Dec 30 2019... are you sure you got your facts right?

Comment: What exactly is crashing, IntelliJ IDEA or your app?

Comment: @Eugene I just made a copy paste from one of the log files but the same error remains on the newest logs too

Comment: @Eugene The same error is also discussed in this github thread: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-support/issues/26 and it seems like affecting versions: 8, 11.0.2, 12, 13

Comment: @CrazyCoder I don't think it's IntelliJ or my app 'cause 70% of my executions the apps are working and for no reason the crash happens, Intellij notifies me that one of my microservices app has stopped and I found a new file log with the details of the crash in my home folder. I'm using ubuntu as OS.

Comment: Run http://www.memtest86.com/ to ensure it's not a hardware issue.

Comment: @CrazyCoder That's what I did today, 'cause I was thinking about a RAM problem, I changed them just today with new ones that we just received at the company using the right frequency for the dell XPS 15 model that I have which is 2400Mhz and ran memtest86 with the tech staff, we got no errors.

Comment: The crash dump you've shared belongs to IntelliJ IDEA process, but you state that IntelliJ IDEA keeps running and doesn't crash. I don't understand it. The question is also titled "JDK 8 ...", while IntelliJ IDEA uses JetBrains Runtime 11 and the dump is from Java 11 which adds even more confusion.

Comment: @CrazyCoder My Java apps are developped and run using Intellij. The app itself is being compiled and intellij shows me that it's running correcly in the services tab, however the app crash but Intellij is still working. The green play icon at the right of the app become a red exclamation mark and the first lines of the logs that I shared with you are displayed in Intellij console.

Comment: You should share the relevant crash dump from your app then, not from IntelliJ IDEA as you say it doesn't crash and is also using a different Java version.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'll do so by tomorrow and will update my question. Thank you for your precious feedbacks.